# How to add responsive media query for basic blogger template

Tags: templates, responsive

How to add responsive media query for basic blogger template, i tried both google results but never see find. finally i decide asked experts . how to do this ?

this is my blog site [Gossip Lanka](http://www.gossiplankahot-news.com/)  anyone help me how to create this template more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to display your blog on a smaller device such as mobile, you will want to add, in your css files, @media queries. For a smartphone device such as a Samsung Galaxy S5, you will want something like this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px){
           #id or .class{
                  code...
          }
}
```

Also, you will need in your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

for this to work.

Adding these queries will adjust your CSS when being displayed on a mobile device. There are other width sizes ect you can research for other sized devices, like a tablet.